# Set adjustment layer to only affect certain layers without using groups?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

As far as I'm concerned, there are a few different ways to control which layers are affected by an adjustment layer, for example:

- move the adjustment layer down so that only the layers below it are affected
- alt-click on the line between the adjustment layer and the layer below it to create a clipping mask
- create a group and clip the adjustment layer to the group, again using alt-click

However, using these methods there is no way to have an adjustment layer affect multiple layers that aren't next to each other in the layer order.

So let's say I have a Photoshop document with 10 layers and I want one adjustment layer to affect only the 3rd, the 7th and the 9th layer without rearranging the layers, is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could put the stack of layers at the bottom and then merge them with the adjustment layer, but then you'll lose the adjustment capability. -_-

Comment: Which would be completely destructive, so I don't want that, obviously ;)

Comment: Yup, but what you can do is group your original layers and hide them so if you need to make changes you'll have a backup. It's not ideal, but its an option.

Comment: Layer mask **or** Clipping mask with multiple layers + the adjustment lauers **or** Clipping mask where Smart object holds the elements you want to mask out + the adjustment layers.

Comment: What do you mean by "Clipping mask with multiple layers + the adjustment layers"?
The Smart Object is a good idea, however that would remove the layers from my original document. The background of my question is that I want to be able to apply several adjustment layers to different layers independently. So in the example above, e.g. have one hue/saturation layer affect the layers 1, 4 and 5, one brightness layer affect the layer 3, 5 and 9 and one color balance layer affect the layers 4, 7 and 9, which is impossible if I group the layers to apply one adjustment layer to it.

Comment: It turns out I didn't read the question properly . Well if you wanna go that route, you'd actually have to use Layer mask (maybe), but depending on what you're doing, it can be less than ideal. It would make it easier to give a precise answer if you could show the document where you need this to happen or at least a good representation of it. The goal seems to be that if you ever need to change the brightness of specific set of elements ( ...or color or what ever ), you only have to edit one adjustment layer, correct?

Comment: I don't have a document where I need to do this right now. However, I had situations where this would have been very helpful. I found workarounds, but I still want to know if the described usage of adjustment layers is possible, since I find this would be useful in lots of situations. 
Yes, you are right, I want to apply different adjustment layers to different content layers, so that I'll be able to change the adjustments later on, without being held back in the process of editing by the layer groups that I had to use to apply one adjustment layer to multiple content layers.

Comment: Also, it would be virtually impossible to apply different adjustments to groups of layers that overlap.
So in the example in my comment above, if I arrange the layers 1, 4 and 5 in a group so that I can apply the hue/saturation layer to that group, there is no way to apply the brightness layer to only the layers 3, 5 and 9, since layer 5 is already in the first group that I used the hue/saturation layer on. That is the problem that led me to asking this question.

Comment: I would use a layer mask on an adjustment layer method. Command-click on the 1st layer, then Shift+Cmd-click on the other layers, gets you your selection, them make an adjustment layer. .. you can link the layers together to keep them organized if you want.

Comment: If you want separate layers with individual adjustments, you can use layer styles for some things. but you would have to select all the layers to change to a new saved layer style to make revisions. - not ideal

Comment: Hm still not optimal, since the adjustment layer created from the selection will affect everything in the selected section of the image, regardless of the layer ... well maybe there just is no way to get the result I am aiming for right now, I'll probably write a future request for that feature to Adobe °ω°

Answer (score 35):

If you use Photoshop CC, just click on the clip button at the bottom of the adjustment popup. This will clip the adjustment layer to the layer below it, which means your adjustment will only affect that layer. You can have your adjustment affect more than one layer by grouping the layers, then clip the adjustment layer to the group. Likewise, the adjustment layer should be above the group to which you clip it to.!

The keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Opt</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> on Windows).

[image: The button in Properties for clipping an adjustment layer]

Comment: Hi silkscrim, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: This doesn’t actually answer the question. The question is specifically whether you can apply an adjustment to any layers of your choosing that are _not_ adjacent and _without_ grouping them.

Answer (score 5):

Bit late but I'm not sure why simple Layer Masks can't do this for you.

Let's say you have a picture with foreground a person, middle ground a mountain, middle ground a waterfall, background the sky. You want to push the blues in the Sky and Person so you make a Curves Adjustment and mask out the Mountain and Waterfall. Then you want to adjust the brightness of the Person and Mountain. Okay another Curves Adjustment but mask out the Sky and Waterfall.

It's irrelevant that the Mountain Layer is not next to the Sky for example. If it were to make a difference than you wouldn't be able to see the Sky since the Mountain would be blocking it. So both objects must be visible at least partially thus Layer Mask on your Adjustment Layer can block out specific parts.

To formally answer your question though - no there's no way to have an Adjustment Layer set to affect a few specific ungrouped layers. But as I said above, I'm not sure why you'd really need to.